# Gram-Schmidt Procedure

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials, gram-schmidt

What does it mean for a set of functions
$\{f_0, f_1, f_2, . . . , f_N\}$
to form an orthonormal set on the interval $[a,b]$?
Use the Gram-Schmidt procedure to transform the set of
polynomials $\{1, x, x^2\}$ into an orthonormal set on the interval
$[−1, 1]$.

I know that that the sets are
[image: the sets to use]

However, I don't know how to apply them. Any help would be fully appreciated.

Comment: That's not what a "set" means

Comment: What does the notation $(P_1,Q_0)$ mean to you?  That's key to understanding the first part of the problem, and also how to do the procedure.

Comment: It means that the functions satisfy $\langle f_i, f_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$ where the inner product is represented by $\int_a^b f_i f_j dx$